# mouseEntered function does not work

Tags: java

I try to write this piece of code to run the mouseEntered method. When I put something in the mouseEntered, it just does not work while when I put the output order in the mouseMoved function, it works(it means the terminal shows the output). How can I make the mouseEntered function work?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TetrisGUI implements ActionListener{

JButton quit = new JButton();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
JPanel mainArea = new JPanel();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TetrisGUI gui = new TetrisGUI();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    quit = new JButton("QUIT");
    label1 = new JLabel("Level:        1");
    label2 = new JLabel("Lines:        0");
    label3 = new JLabel("Score:        0");

    quit.addActionListener(this);
    mainArea.addMouseMotionListener(new CustomListener(){});

    MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(quit);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label3);
    frame.add(mainArea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);

    label1.setSize(100,200);
    label1.setLocation(310,60);
    label2.setSize(100,200);
    label2.setLocation(310,110);
    label3.setSize(100,200);
    label3.setLocation(310,160);
    mainArea.setSize(250,500);
    mainArea.setLocation(20,50);
    quit.setSize(100,40);
    quit.setLocation(300,310);
    frame.setSize(400,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    mainArea.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    mainArea.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
}


}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(20,50,250,500);//Main Area
    g.drawRect(300,50,100,70);//NextShape

    g.drawRect(145,80,25,25);//Tian Block
    g.drawRect(145,105,25,25);
    g.drawRect(120,80,25,25);
    g.drawRect(120,105,25,25);
    Color deepGreen = new Color(51,138,52);
    g.setColor(deepGreen); 
    g.fillRect(121,81,24,24);//Tian Block
    g.fillRect(121,106,24,24);
    g.fillRect(146,81,24,24);
    g.fillRect(146,106,24,24);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(245,525,25,25);//Right bottom
    g.drawRect(220,525,25,25);
    g.drawRect(195,525,25,25);
    g.drawRect(170,525,25,25);
    g.drawRect(245,500,25,25);
    g.drawRect(245,475,25,25);
    g.drawRect(220,500,25,25);
    g.drawRect(195,500,25,25);
    Color deepBlue = new Color(15,66,148);
    g.setColor(deepBlue);
    g.fillRect(246,526,24,24);
    g.fillRect(221,526,24,24);
    g.fillRect(246,501,24,24);
    g.fillRect(246,476,24,24);
    Color brightYellow = new Color(252,238,33);
    g.setColor(brightYellow);
    g.fillRect(196,526,24,24);
    g.fillRect(171,526,24,24);
    g.fillRect(196,501,24,24);
    g.fillRect(221,501,24,24);

    //NextShape Blocks
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(360,60,25,25);
    g.drawRect(335,85,25,25);
    g.drawRect(360,85,25,25);
    g.drawRect(310,85,25,25);
    Color deepRed = new Color(227,23,36);
    g.setColor(deepRed);
    g.fillRect(361,61,24,24);
    g.fillRect(336,86,24,24);
    g.fillRect(361,86,24,24);
    g.fillRect(311,86,24,24);
}
}

class CustomListener implements MouseMotionListener {
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){

}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){
    System.out.println("PAUSE");
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}
}
```

Comment: Add a visible border to your `mainArea` JPanel to see if you are really entering it when you believe you do.

Comment: I have set the size and location of the area and when my mouse enter the area, mouseMoved function does work.

Comment: @Czon You don't control the size or position of the components, they are controlled by the `LayoutManager`, once the frame is validated, anything your supplied is likely to be discarded...

Answer (score 1):

You "main" problem is here...

```
frame.getContentPane().add(quit);
frame.getContentPane().add(label1);
frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
frame.getContentPane().add(label3);
frame.add(mainArea);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
```

Basically, the default layout manager for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, the default position used by `BorderLayout` (when you don't specify one) is `BorderLayout.CENTER`, so all the components you are adding are been placed at the `CENTER` position, but only one component will be recognized as occupying that position, the last one you have added.

In fact, I would consider adding the `MouseListener` to your `drawPanel` any way, but that's me ;)

Using `setSize` and `setLocation` on the components will have no effect, as the layout manager will take over once the frame needs to be validated.

I would suggest making use of different layout managers, within multiple containers, this will make it easier to manage the individual requirements of each section.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details...

Also, make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting.